# CakeEmail manda email sem mensagem

Tags: cakephp, envio-de-email

Estou a tentar fazer um formulário para enviar um email. Este é enviado correctamente e com o nome da pessoa, que se insere no formulário, no sitio certo, no subject do email. No entanto nem o email que essa pessoa insere, nem o corpo da mensagem, aparecem. Apenas aparece `This email was sent using the CakePHP Framework, http://cakephp.org.`. Como se resolve este problema?

Estou a utilizar a versão 2.4.4 do CakePHP.

**Controller**

```
<?php
class ContactsController extends AppController {
public function ShowContactUs(){
    $this->layout='default';
    $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Contactos');
}
public function Contact() {

    $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Contactos');
    $this->loadModel('Contact');
    if($this->request->is('post')) {

        $this->Contact->set($this->request->data);
        if($this->Contact->validates(array('fieldList' => array('name','email','message')))) {

            $email = new CakeEmail();
            $email->config('gmail')
                ->from(array('my.site.contact@gmail.com' => 'mysite'))
                ->to('ideografismoteste@gmail.com')
                ->subject('mysite.com - Contacto - ' .  $this->request->data['Contact']['name'])
                ->emailFormat('text')
                ->template('default')
                ->viewVars(array(
                    'notificationType' => 'Contacto',
                    'message' => $this->request->data['Contact']['message'],
                    'name' => $this->request->data['Contact']['name'],
                    'email' => $this->request->data['Contact']['email'],
                    'title_for_layout' => 'Contacto'
                ))
                ->send();
                //debug($email);
                //die;
                $this->request->data = null;

                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Contact submitted successfully.'), 'Flash/success');

        } else {

            $error = $this->Notification->validationErrors;
            $this->set('error', $error);

            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Fill all fields'), 'Flash/warning');

        }
    }

}

}
?>
```

**View *ShowContactUs()***

```
<h3>Contactos</h3>

<style type="text/css">
div.inline { float:left;
    padding-left: 2%; }
.clearBoth { clear:both; }
h3{
  color:#A80000 ;
  text-align: left;
}
div{text-align:justify;}
</style>

<br>
<div>
<p>Contacto Permanente: xxxxxxxxx</p>
<p>Email: xxxxxxx</p>
</div>
<div id="contact-form">

<div class="well">

    <?php echo $this->Form->create('Contact', array('url' => array('controller' => 'Contacts', 'action' => 'Contact'), 'class' => 'form-horizontal')) ?>

        <?php echo $this->Form->input('name', array('label' => __('Name') . ' *', 'class' => 'input-xlarge')); ?>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('email', array('label' => __('E-mail') . ' *', 'class' => 'input-xlarge')); ?>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('message', array('label' => __('Message') . ' *', 'class' => 'input-xxlarge', 'type' => 'textarea', 'rows' => 3)); ?>

        <?php echo $this->Form->submit(__('Enviar'), array('class' => 'btn btn-success')) ?>

    <?php echo $this->Form->end() ?>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Qual o nome deste aquivo *view*?

Comment: @ErlonCharles a view é a `show_contact_us.ctp`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note que pela [**documentação**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html#sending-templated-emails), você precisa definir o template no momento que você cria as configurações, e atualmente você utiliza o template *default*, que não o mesmo que você criou e mostrou em sua pergunta.

Então você pode fazer algo assim:

```
->template('show_contact_us')
```

Sendo que este arquivo deve estar no diretório `app/View/Emails/html/`.

Comment: Exatamente por isso que eu perguntei o nome da view, isso vai corrigir o problema corretamente.